# lightning:recordForm does not display fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components, summer-18, lightning-record-form

I'm having trouble using the new lightning:recordForm component. Here is my code :

```
<aura:attribute 
  name="fieldsArray" 
  type="String[]" 
  default="['Name','Email','Phone','AccountId']" 
/>

<lightning:recordForm 
  aura:id="recordForm" 
  objectApiName="Account" 
  fields="{!v.fieldsArray}" 
  columns="2" 
  mode="edit" 
  onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
/>
```

There is no fields displayed. Only the buttons Cancel and Save.

I've tried to use that in an application and in a component of the utility bar. No success...

Any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: have you checked the list of known issues on that component, there seems to be quite the list.

Comment: do you have a link ? I'm struggling to filter the know issues only for that component... and only displaying 20 per page.

Comment: @LucasEnnouchi It looks like they copied your code and used it as the repro... although, looks like this may only be an issue when previewing from the Developer Console (fingers crossed) https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000oAQnQAM

Comment: 'AccountId' is not a valid field. Maybe you were going for 'ParentId' or just 'Id'? Check that your controller/helpers also don't reference the non-existent 'AccountId'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Closing this as the best the configuration of my component was wrong (AccountId as a field for the Account object).

Answer (score 2):

your're propably missing recordId argument.
Try :

```
<lightning:recordForm 
  recordId="{!v.recordId}"
  aura:id="recordForm" 
  objectApiName="Account" 
  fields="{!v.fieldsArray}" 
  columns="2" 
  mode="edit" 
  onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
/>
```